# Random Forest Classifier With Very High Success Rate

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I'm having a weird problem that may suprise you all. My classification rate is too high on my test set. I'm using scikit-learn packages, and I'm very suspicious of these classification rates, as they are very close to 1.

```
x=[]
for nums in range(1,100):   
  X=maxDataset[:,1:]
  y=maxDataset[:,0]
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
  cvIter=ShuffleSplit(X_train.shape[0], n_iter=10, test_size=0.2)
  clf=RandomForestClassifier() 
  clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
  clf.fit(X, y)
  avg=metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,clf.predict(X_test))
  x.append(avg)
xMean=np.average(x)
print(xMean)
```

Is something wrong with my evaluation? I was suspicious that this could be due to fitting the model on the entire data set. If this is the case, or something else is the problem,how can I fix it to get an accurate evaluation of the classifier? The xMean ranges form 98.3 to 99.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you do the fit twice?  Your second fit (`fit(X, y)`) overrides the earlier one, which means yes, you are fitting on the whole data set.

Comment: I suggest you use ``cross_val_score`` from sklearn.cross_validation. That would replace your code with the line ``cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(), maxDataset[:, 1:], maxDataset[:, 0])`` (thought that would use k-fold, not shuffle split. you can also pass cv=ShuffleSplit(...).